# Robospice faces Error but onRequestSuccess is called

Tags: java, android, robospice

I am POSTing to server a request but when I face a

> Client org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400
>   BAD REQUEST

the `onRequestSuccess` is called instead of `onRequestFailure`

```
public String loadDataFromNetwork()  {

   String url =  "myurl";

    HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
    header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "json"));

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject =  new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put(constants.TAG_ORDER_ID, bOrderID);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(true);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());

        HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>( jsonObject.toString() , header);


        ResponseEntity r = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, getResultType());

        return r.toString();
    }
    catch (HttpClientErrorException e){
        return String.valueOf(e);
    }
    catch (JSONException e){
        return String.valueOf(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your url is working in normal browser??

Comment: Mostly 400 error is caused by malformed url.

Comment: I have purposefully corrupted the URL to get a 400 error, My problem is why it is calling onRequestSuccess ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are catching the exceptions inside `loadDataFromNetwork()` and not rethrowing them, RoboSpice thinks that nothing unusual has happened. The only way to propagate the error is to throw it from your `loadDataFromNetwork()` and then you will be called back through `onRequestFailure`.